# parse json response in android parse json object details with json array

Tags: android, json

This is my json response.

```
"hits" : [ {
    "recipe" : {
      "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_ef498d1ca2ecb7104aa72d516af211d8",
      "label" : "A Potato Dish for Julia Recipe",
      "image" : "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/9bd/9bd993aeafaf4a439a59b5689ea6153f.jpg",
```

i need to get this as my list view response, i tried to add this by many ways but still i am getting blank screen as respose.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray hits = jsonObj.getJSONArray("hits");
                    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject h = hits.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject recipe = h.getJSONObject("recipe");
                        String Uri = recipe.getString("uri");
                        String Label = recipe.getString("label");
                        String Image = recipe.getString("image");
                        HashMap<String, String> recipe_ = new HashMap<>();
                        recipe_.put("uri", Uri);
                        recipe_.put("label", Label);
                        recipe_.put("image", Image);
                        recipeList.add(recipe_);
```

This is my solution what i was finding to call json object details by first calling json array then its object.

Comment: post your adapter class and activity from where you are setting the adapter

Comment: in using AsyncTask for api call, im new in android and trying to get response by using some given online examples.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Did you parse the JSON reponse into a POJO i.e. a Java object?

Comment: i got the ans thanks for your response.